# Identifying correct column value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iZkAtyY2vwJUnpwStILr8M1BxaMMV0jI0WDN78kxDtk/edit#gid=0

so i want the 1st sheet to sort the rank colum by itself and the 2nd sheet to sort the comp colum by itself as well. This is the coding ive done so far but its not working.

```js
function myFunction() {
  function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
SHEET_NAME = "The Resistance { Member Roster )";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "E5:E1183";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 5, ascending: true},  // 5 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 4, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order
];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');

SHEET_NAME = "The Resistance ( War Roster )";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "C5:C63";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 3, ascending: true},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 2, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order
];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
}
```

i added a copy of the google docs if anyone can try to fix it , thanks you so much !

i watched youtube video and read some tutorial but im struggling with correctly identifing the correct colum value.

Comment: I think here it only sorts the variables in APP Script, but not your Sheet.
Does it work if you use a named range?

You name the range "E5:E1183" in GSheet. Then use:
var namedRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('MyNamedRange');

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `i want the 1st sheet to sort the rank colum by itself and the 2nd sheet to sort the comp colum by itself as well`, you want to sort with column "E" of `The Resistance{ Member Roster )` sheet, and sort with column C of `The Resistance( War Roster )` sheet.

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, even when `myFunction()` is run, no script is run. Please be careful about this.
- When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that the sheet names are not correct. By this, the script is not correctly run.

  - `The Resistance { Member Roster )` is required to be modified to `The Resistance{ Member Roster )`.
  - `The Resistance ( War Roster )` is required to be modified to `The Resistance( War Roster )`.
- In your goal, you want to sort column "E" of `The Resistance{ Member Roster )` sheet, and sort column C of `The Resistance( War Roster )` sheet. But, in your script, 2 columns are used.
- In this case, I thought that you might have wanted to sort "B5:K1183" with column "E" of `The Resistance{ Member Roster )` sheet and also  have wanted to sort "B5:H63" with column "C" of `The Resistance( War Roster )` sheet.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  multiSortColumns();
}

function multiSortColumns() {
  SHEET_NAME = "The Resistance{ Member Roster )";
  SORT_DATA_RANGE = "B5:K1183";
  SORT_ORDER = [{ column: 5, ascending: true }];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);

  SHEET_NAME = "The Resistance( War Roster )";
  SORT_DATA_RANGE = "B5:H63";
  SORT_ORDER = [{ column: 3, ascending: true }];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);

  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

#### Note:

- When I saw your Google Apps Script project, I found the same function names in the same Google Apps Script project. In this case, please rename other functions. When you test the script without renaming the functions, the script is not correctly run. Please be careful about this.
- I tested this modified script using your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.